# Advanced bar plot labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

Is there a way to label bars through binding values and bars by lines, without text overlapping, like on the picture below? Should I write a complex script which evaluate free coordinates for drawing lines and text or exist simple way? Thx.

[image: Labels example]

Comment: I don't think matplotlib has a pre-canned method to lay out [annotations](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) in a way where they are guaranteed to not overlap. There are a bajillion libraries built on MPL though, maybe one can help (it might also help to search for your specific domain too, a la "mass spec matplotlib plotting")